# Twitter bootstrap change active on navbar

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried just about every iteration I can find to get this working.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <img src="tile.png" alt="Brand">
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-inverse collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
```

that is the navbar portion I am working on.

I have tried the following js/jquery at different times.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navbar-left li').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});




$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$(".navbar-nav a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
});


$('.navbar-nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
        var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
        var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
        $(".act span").text(x);
        $(".prev span").text(y);
    });
});


// Select all tabs
$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
})

// Select tab by name
$('.navbar-nav a[href="#home"]').tab('show')

// Select first tab
$('.navbar-nav a[href="#features"]').tab('show')

// Select last tab
$('.navbar-nav a[href="#testimonials"]').tab('show')

// Select fourth tab (zero-based)
$('.navbar-nav a[href="#contact-us"]').tab('show')
```

*The last one above works to move the active, but doesn't actually navigate

```
var menu = document.querySelector('nav.ul');
var anchors = menu.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i += 1) {
  anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function() { clickHandler(anchors[i]) }, false);
}

function clickHandler(anchor) {
  var hasClass = anchor.getAttribute('class');
  if (hasClass !== 'active') {
    anchor.setAttribute('class', 'active');
  }
}
```

Most of them don't do anything, but the ones that do work to change the active highlight when you click it doesn't actually navigate.  What am I missing here?  All I need this thing too do is change the highlight and navigate to the link.

Comment: Why are you mixing vanilla JS and jQuery?

Comment: Can you make a http://jsbin.com/ Snippet or a snippet here?

Comment: Kumar, I'm not mixing them.  I have tried each of these solutions individually even though they are in one code block, I am not using them all at the same time.  For some reason I couldn't get the code tag to separate the individual pieces.

Comment: Call me **Praveen**, please. What exactly you wanna achieve?

Comment: Praveen,

http://jsbin.com/niyosazewe/edit?html,output

you see that using the very first code on my list I tried that it moves the active selection on the navbar, but doesn't actually navigate when clicked

Comment: Do you have only that JavaScript written?

Comment: Praveen, I need to move the active highlight on the navbar when each of the navbar items is clicked.  I can accomplish that, but for some reason when I accomplish that it no longer actually navigates when clicked; it just moves the active highlight.

Comment: Did you even understand the question I asked? I asked, is the JavaScript that you used for your own code, the one in the middle part of JSBin, is that all?

Comment: Praveen, I answered that it is one of the ones I have tried; so yes it is my own code and the only one in there right now.  Do you understand my answer?

Comment: Right. Then something else is interfering... `:(` Need to find what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navbar-left li').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

this one worked; I had a problem with indentation and a missin ) messing up the code the first time and didn't notice it.